# Should code-only answers that promote the author's library be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76885437/6879826) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76885225/6879826) posted in rapid succession by the same author. Both answers self-identify as shameless self-plugs and provide links to a library written by the author. In fact, both answers share identical non-code text and links (modulo a typo):

> Shameless self-plug. You can use my string library; it supports string
> splitting ([link-here]).

These answers each go on to provide solutions to their OP questions in code, but without any discussion of the problems they solve or of how the library code solves those problems.

It seems that SO is tolerant of self-promotion to a point and also tolerant of code-only answers to a point. Self-promotion and code-only style seem to be combined in these two answers in a way that may have passed the point of toleration. I'm not sure that these answers provide any useful information; that makes these answers downvote candidates at the least.

Should answers such as these be flagged, and if so how should they be flagged, or do these answers meet the acceptability criteria for SO?

Comment: If you can repeat an answer verbatim you've either misinterpreted the question or it should be closed as a duplicate of the other

Comment: Recommeding a library you created isn't against the rules, provided you aren't doing it in *every* answer and it's explicitly on topic. The real problem is that the 2 answers are identical, which isn't allowed; an answer should be bespoke to the question asked. If the 2 question warrant identical answers then flagging/voting to close as a duplicate should be done of which ever is the better™ Q&A.

Comment: @ThomA -- so are you saying that if only one of these answers was posted it would be OK? That is, it's OK to answer a question with: "Just use my library" and a code snippet using said library without explanation or comments?

Comment: Within reason, yes, as long as the answer is still an answer and not just a link.

Comment: Re *"tolerant of code-only answers to a point"*: Many code-only answers are likely ***completely bogus*** (especially late answers), but no one has the inclination to check them. Much is probably blindly copied off some more or less arbitrary web page without ***any*** understanding of it, including from other Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: cont' - The modern version is ChatGPT-generated code, with or without the (verbose) explaining text. Though the [Jon Skeet Decree](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/14/podcast-123-jon-skeet-wants-you-to-be-a-feminist/)-compliant comments should aid in detection.

Comment: Note that even if an answer isn’t against the rules, that doesn’t automatically make it helpful. For example, the second linked answer doesn’t even seem to answer the question.

Comment: "_You can use **my** string library_" is a clear statement of affiliation. See also [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: This is far better than self-promotion answers that only link to a library. It demonstrates how to use the library, and explicitly declares it is their library. Could it have been a better answer, yes it could do with some explanation and details, but it is an answer, and it falls within the self-promotion rules.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> It seems that SO is tolerant of self-promotion to a point

Yes, see the [self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). If an answer starts with "*Shameless self-plug. You can use my […] library*", this is totally fine. **Do not flag it.**

> It's a code-only answer, without any discussion of the problems they solve or of how the library code solves those problems.

Then that makes it a *bad* answer. **Downvote it**, possibly comment on it.
Depending on the topic, a detailed explanation of the intricate solution approaches might too much detail for an answer, and "use a library" might be appropriate advice. Use your good judgement.

You may still use a custom flag for moderator attention if a user spams a lot of questions (say, more than 3?) with similar low-quality answers, *and* doesn't want to stop despite clear feedback. Moderators are human exception handlers, they can give the user a stern talk and suspend them if they won't listen.